# How can I get thin (the webserver) to be accessible outside of my home network?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I followed the simple instructions for installing the "thin" web server in my ruby application via: http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/

I can see that it is being called when I "start" it.  However, while I am able to access the web server using "localhost".  I would like to be able to access it using my ip address, or some other way - so that I can send a colleague that's not on my home network to my test app.

while I have fiddled around with some variables (port, host, etc) I am still missing something.

How can I access my thin server from outside of my home network?

Note: I do not have a firewall enabled.  - Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: What the command you're using to run thin?

Comment: `http://localhost:<think.port>/` should show your default page if it server is running. Your next task is to try `http://<your.ip.address>:<thin.port>/` from **the same** machine. If this works, you'll need to open up the *<thin.port>* on your router and have that passed to *<thin.port>* on *<ip.address>*. Try http://<public.ip>:<thin.port>/ first from **the same** machine then from a different machine. If they all work, give out `http://<public.ip>:<thin.port>` to everyone.

Comment: Command I am using: "thin --port 20 start".  On localhost it works, using my ip address it doesn't.  That is the problem I am trying to solve.  I also tried port 80, I am now researching my router to see if there is something there I need to configure

Comment: You need to bind thin to your ip address

Comment: how do I bind thin to my ip address

Comment: @rockit `thin -a 192.168.1.45 start`

Comment: This is likely a NAT issue, rather than a Rails or Thin issue. Google for "port forwarding."

Comment: thank you h1 - you solved my problem / ahmad - thanks for the startup tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a network issue than a server setting issue.

You would probably need to set your router to redirect incoming accesses to your computer, how to do will vary from router to router.

In most cases there should be a menu in the router that lets you specify a port, and what internal IP address you want the request to be routed to, set that to your machines LAN IP address, and it should be good to go.

You will probably get a better answer at Server Fault or Super User.

Comment: More comment than answer